# How to create custom alert dialog box with angular material 15 dialog box

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

first I created custom dialog module then generate its component and then its service...

```
files
-custom-dialog
--custom-dialog.component.html
--custom-dialog.component.css
--custom-dialog.component.ts
--custom-dialog.module.ts
--custom-dialog.service.ts
```

First import mat dialog in module

custom-dialog.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CustomDialogComponent } from './custom-dialog.component';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CustomDialogComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatDialogModule
  ],
  exports: [
    CustomDialogComponent
  ]
})
export class CustomDialogComponent { }
```

custom-dialog.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { CustomDialogComponent } from './custom-dialog.component';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CustomDialogService {

  constructor(
    private dialog: MatDialog
  ) { }

  alert() {
    this.dialog.open(DialogComponent);
  }
}
```

custom-dialog.component.ts

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-dialog',
  templateUrl: './custom-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-dialog.component.scss']
})
export class CustomDialogComponent {

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<CustomDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any
  ) {}

}
```

custom-dialog.component.html

```
<mat-dialog-content>
 alert
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions align="end">
    <button type="button" mat-button mat-dialog-close>close</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

this is the code what I write for show alert.

to call this function first i import **CustomDialogModule** in where i have to call it and import **CustomDialogService** in component and call alert function which created in service but it shows error in console

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(WebsiteSessionModule)[DialogService -> DialogService -> MatDialog -> MatDialog -> MatDialog]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialog!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(WebsiteSessionModule)[DialogService -> DialogService -> MatDialog -> MatDialog -> MatDialog]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialog!
```

but when i import **matdialogmodule** in **app.module.ts** instead of **custom-dialog.module.ts** its works fine but i don't want to call it in app module.

Answer (score 0):

So both CustomDialogService and CustomDialogComponent are the same as yours.

**CustomDialogModule**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CustomDialogComponent } from './custom-dialog/custom-dialog.component';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [CustomDialogComponent],
  exports: [CustomDialogComponent],
  imports: [
    MatDialogModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
  ],
})
export class CustomDialogModule {}
```

**PagesModule**

This is where I use the CustomDialogModule

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ActionComponent } from './action/action.component';
import { CustomDialogModule } from '../custom-dialog/custom-dialog.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ActionComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, CustomDialogModule],
})
export class PagesModule {}
```

**AppModule**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, PagesModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: This method not working - Argument of type '{ providedIn: "root"; providers: (typeof MatDialog)[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '({ providedIn: "root" | Type<any> | "platform" | "any" | null; } & InjectableProvider) | undefined'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'providers' does not exist in type '{ providedIn: "root" | Type<any> | "platform" | "any" | null; } & InjectableProvider'.ts(2345)

Comment: Tried replicating the error but I didn't have any problem, so I think your problem might be in the modules. I'll edit the code so you can see what I have.